# Is there a way go get a single field from redis hashes

Tags: php, redis

I've a redis cached filled with items like this (100k+):

```
redis:6379> hgetall key1
1) "counter"
2) "100"

redis:6379> hgetall key2
1) "counter"
2) "200"
```

How can I get (in a single call) both counter-values from key1 and key2, e.g. in pseudocode something like this

```
hmgetall key1 key2 counter
```

I've tried with commands like SUNION, HMGET and HMGETALL, but I didn't find a solution for my problem. Does someone has an idea for me? The answer: "That's technically not possible!" would also be ok... then I'll have to try something else.

Based to the anwser of @for_stack I tried:

```
$call = "local res = {}; for k, v in pairs(ARGV[1]) do res[#res + 1] = redis.call(\"hget\", v, \"counter\") end; return res";

$args = [];
$args[] = "2";
$args[] = "key1 key2";
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect($host, $port);
$counter = $redis->eval($call, $args, 1);
```

If I dump $counter I'll get "0". What's wrong with that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Lua script](https://redis.io/commands/eval) to do the job.

```
eval 'local res = {}; local field = ARGV[1]; for k, v in pairs(KEYS) do res[#res + 1] = redis.call("hget", v, field) end; return res;' 2 key1 key2 counter
```

Comment: Good idea: It's works well on cli. How can I use this in PHP with Redis. I testet witrh $redis=new Redis(); $redis->eval(), but I didn't figure out how to explode it correctly in $redis->eval($script, $args). I just updated my question based on your script.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP. You might need to ask help from a PHP expert.